# R: Filtering data by rows

Tags: r

I have multiple data sets and which one of them has a variable identifying an individual, which I will call ID. I'm trying to find to figure out which ID's appear in all of the data sets in order to trim my data. What is the best way about doing this? Some of the data has more than a million rows so I need a really efficient way to filter my data.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show some example data and your expected output based on that example so that it will be easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you datasets are called `dat1`, `dat2`, `dat3`, and the ID columns in each dataset are called ID you could use this approach:

```
commonIDs <- Reduce(intersect, list(dat1$ID, dat2$ID, dat3$ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

use `dplyr`

```
filter(your_data_frame, id == 1, id2 == "name")
```

more info + examples
http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html